# An application on a computer emits data to a COM port. What are my options to read this data on a different computer?

Tags: networking, usb, serial-port

An external system (not ours) can be configured to emit serial data to a COM port on a Windows computer. What we want to do is read the data on another computer. This computer only has USB ports available for us to connect to.

What we have done before is buy two [USB TO RS232 WIRE END](https://ftdichip.com/products/usb-rs232-we-1800-bt_5-0/), and wire TX to TX and RX to RX with a 2pin cable. The distance is about 8-10 meters. I am wondering perhaps this is a more cumbersome solution than we need.

Is there a USB A serial to USB a serial product, or a combination of adapters that we could use to produce the same results as we currently have? So we don't have to solder or manually wire anything, just plug the cables.

Would perhaps a usb-to-serial, serial cable, usb-to-serial combination work?

So, two [usb-to-serial](https://www.ebay.com/itm/192364408317?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=zRWbBoKiRPC&sssrc=2047675&ssuid=&widget_ver=artemis&media=COPY), and one [serial female-female cable](https://www.ebay.com/itm/351895345969?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=RIs2ZnIhRUq&sssrc=2047675&ssuid=&widget_ver=artemis&media=COPY). Or, perhaps the "straight-through" part means that it will be RX-to-RX/TX-to-TX and not RX-to-TX/TX-to-RX.

EDIT: Both computers only have USB ports available.

Comment: Do both machines have either a 9-pin or 25-pin RS232 header? If so, you can use/make (if you have a soldering iron and some connectors) a null-modem cable with RX & TX pins crossed, and the ground pin connected (pin 5 on a 9-pin port). Your workaround seems to be the USB-RS232 at the target end, in place of an absent port, is that correct?

Comment: You are correct. There is only usb ports, on both machines.

Comment: Also I should add that I would rather not have to do any soldering or use screw connectors. Preferably it should just be pluggable connectors.

Comment: What can you do on the source computer? If it was virtual, redirecting a COM port would(?) be easy ([example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/serialports.html)). In the current situation, can you install or use some driver that provides a virtual COM port? I don't know Windows, but in Linux `socat` can generate a pty that can be used like a serial line; and relay data to whatever (e.g. via TCP to `socat` on the other computer). *Maybe* you can do something similar in Windows.

Comment: The source computer is not ours. So basically all we can do is plug into a USB port to read the data. When we plug in our USB-to-RS232 adapter, a COM port with some address appears on the computer and the "manager" of the computer configures his application to send data on this particular COM port.

Comment: Please [edit] and add all your clarifications from comments to the question body, so the question itself contains all the information.

Comment: I have edited the question. So it should be more specific now.